# Prepare for segue, what to do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, ios6, segue

i have this XML and parsing it and then i have listed all the main menu at the First UITableViewController and i wanted to List the Sub categories from the XML to the next UITableViewController, Im having a problem with that, like passing the number of the index of the row selected and when reach the destination view controller will check which is it and then show the relevant sub category of that index.

My XML

```
<category>
        <name>Meal</name>
        <description>food description</description>
        <image> Link Here </image>
            <sub_cat>
                <sub_name>Burger</sub_name>
                <sub_desc>sub cat description</sub_desc>
                <sub_image> Link </sub_image>
            </sub_cat>
            <sub_cat>
                <sub_name>Pizza</sub_name>
                <sub_desc>sub cat description</sub_desc>
                <sub_image> Link </sub_image>
            </sub_cat>
</category>
```

this is what my project looks like, where when i click on the Meal Cell then i will go to the other ViewController and show the Burger and Pizza only,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use collection classes like array and dictionary to create your hierarchy through your xm and then just pass the data according to it. 
Like you have created an array of categories then populate the tableview with this, and then you can select any row and can get the indexPath of the row and as well as cell get the title of the cell and populate your next array with the tittle key in your next VC and then use it to populate your view.

Comment: i think thats the thing Im having problem with, what i did here is make a different array for the main menu's and a different array for the sub_menu's, i did try to make an Array of Array but i cant possible get the data right.

Comment: you can make dictionary for categories with their tag name as key and store an array of dictionary with the key of sub categories tag. Or you can create a database where you can create your table as per your hierarchy and then use it through your model.

Comment: i would try to implement the first suggestion you gave me and will try the other one if the first dont fit the things.